# Real versus Virtual images: Multi-Lens systems

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

So I am confused about whether the final image produced by a multi-lens system is virtual or real. Is it just if that if the final image has light rays converging to that point then its real? or is there others things you have to keep in mind? What exactly are the rules qualitatively for this?  !

Comment: Yes, it's just rays converging to a  point.   Rays diverge from a virtual image.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

most of the time you use a multi-lens system for real pictures, like in a foto or a projector. But the multi-lens system can make real or virtual pictures , depending of the distance of the object from the system the same as with normal convex lenses .

Answer (score 1):

Your initial intuition is correct.

A multi-lens system can form real images or virtual images.

A real image is one in which the rays converge to pixels in the image in such a way that you could stick a piece of paper there and see the image focused on  the paper. A virtual image does not actually have rays passing through the image pixels.  Instead it has rays that, if you could extend them backwards, *appear to have come from* image pixels.  It's called a virtual image because you can only focus it, e.g., on paper, by adding another lens to bring those rays to a real focus.